# Userform to specify workbook/worksheet to copy

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate any help on the following....

I am looking to create a userform to import external worksheets from open workbooks into the current workbook - My aim is to use 2 drop down lists and one submit button:

**First drop down box**: Lists all open workbooks - User clicks to specify which is required.

**Second box**: Lists all worksheets within the selected workbook in the first box - User clicks to specify which is required.

**Submit button**: When submit is clicked, the macro will take a copy of the workbook/worksheet combination specified in the dropdown boxes and paste this as a new tab in the main workbook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds good, go for it! What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all workbooks and worksheets in a combo box like they did in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601296/vba-excel-drop-down-list-for-worksheets)

You can link the workbook / worksheet combo boxes by 'dependent drop down list', see this [post](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html).  Note that you need an on-change event fired when the first combo value is selected in order to populate the second combo.

Finally, you can copy worksheets from another workbook as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863940/how-to-copy-sheets-to-another-workbook-using-vba)